# Understanding the position of an image in different browsers

Tags: html, css

I would like to understand CSS more and now I have an example that renders differently in two browsers and in a program called "explorer". Here is the link to the example page that I tried to clean from any disturbing details: http://csaladterapia.hu/example.html

In the latest Firefox version the image is placed inside the fieldset because it is `float:right` and the other elements are `clear:none`. In Chrome and IE the image is placed above the fieldset.

Could you help me understanding the difference?

Comment: For me, the image is sticking out the right side of the fieldset, not entirely within the fieldset. Was that your desired behavior? I'm using Firefox. Also, looking at the source, the div containing image is above the div containing the fieldset, so I can see why it's technically not within it....

Comment: The horizontal alignment is because this is the middle column of the real webpage. When it is so, the horizontal alignment is OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a strange one, and i'm not sure what the correct behavior is here. It is due to the `width` of the `fieldset` being 95%. Removing this width attribute shows the same behavior in Firefox and Chrome.

If you want the image to appear in the `fieldset` then move the image to be the first element after the legend, this way you should see consistent behavior in all browsers.

Firefox tries to honor the `width` of this whilst maintaining the `float` but it seems Chrome wants to move the fieldset onto a new line due to being block and 95% width.

In this case you can change the mark-up as mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

The interpretation of Firefox is wrong, and even very strange. Floating an element should *never* place the element on top of other elements - it just takes them out of the document flow, puts them to the left/right on the current line. If the element following the float is not too wide, and has no 'clear' property, it will be placed on the same line.

In your example the following element is the div, which defaults to 100% width, so it can't be placed on the same line.

What Firefox is doing is very strange - even clear:left on the following element has no effect.

Reference:

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/01/css-float-theory-things-you-should-know/